# windows mobile- leave user logged in for 24 hours

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I'm creating my first Windows Mobile Application.
I have a login screen- I am just wandering, how do I have the user logged in for a period of 24 hours, where it will then ask them for a username and password?

The application will constantly be opened/closed during the day, and I only want them to have to put in their credentials in the morning.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the first time to the database , and check the time different of the first log in time , if the time diff over 24 hrs , delete the row in the table

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a couple of [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) controls and a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) control.

```
private readonly DateTime NODATE = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
private DateTime loginTime;

private void User_Changed(bool loggedIn) {
  if (loggedIn) {
    loginTime = DateTime.Now();
  } else {
    loginTime = NODATE;
  }
}
```

I keep a single Timer running and check the status on various things.

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (loginTime != NODATE) {
    TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now() - loginTime;
    if (24 < span.TotalHours) {
      // Call your Logout routine
    }
  }
}
```